# How to prevent DDOS and encrypt communication on GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I have made a web application (`Play Framework`, `Cassandra`) which I'll not put in production on `GCP` . However, I am not well versed with networking and systems administration. The application would be containerised and I'll use `K8s` to create a cluster containing 2 pods for `Play` web application and 3 pods for `Cassandra` (for replication). There also be a load balancer service in front of the `play` application.

1. I suppose the above configuration is still vulnerable to `DDOS` attack. How can I prevent it on `GCP`?
2. The communication between the `browser` and `server` is not encrypted (eg. the passwords is being sent in plain text. Could could I enable encryption on `GCP`?
3. Any other tips on creating a reliable production system would be much appreciated. So far I have only worked on my laptop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please find the below responses

1. I suppose the above configuration is still vulnerable to DDOS
   attack. How can I prevent it on GCP?

> https://cloud.google.com/files/GCPDDoSprotection-04122016.pdf, this can help you with DDOS protection. If you are using APIGEE, then [APIGEE edge](https://docs.apigee.com/api-platform/get-started/what-apigee-edge) can also help you

2. The communication between the browser and server is not encrypted
   (eg. the passwords is being sent in plain text. Could could I enable
   encryption on GCP?

> you will have to install certificated in general and ensure that the data is sent over a https network. You can also try [sslforfree](https://www.sslforfree.com/)

3. Any other tips on creating a reliable production system would be
   much appreciated. So far I have only worked on my laptop

> since you are using K8s to run cassandra please ensure you are using some sort of volumes to store the data.

Comment: I am confused about sslforfree. It says it's free but also "powered by ZeroSSL with free 90-day certificates". Would you know what this means?

Comment: Can you also please look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65401658/how-to-add-https-load-balancer-for-an-application-deployed-using-gke

Comment: Please look at this https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/sslforfree-com-is-ruined/123164

I don't think it is free anymore!