# How to add HTTPS load balancer for an application deployed using GKE

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, gcp-load-balancer

I have created a `Play` web application which is now deployed on `GCP`. The application works fine. I want to add `https` support in it to secure communication between the client and the server.

I know that in `GCP`, there is an option to create `http load balancers` but I think they are meant for applications running on `VM`s/Compute instances directly and not via `GKE`.

Question 1 - Am I correct? I am asking because when I try to configure the load balancer, I don't see reference to my currently deployed application.

Question 2 - For my application which is deployed using `GKE` on a cluster, how can I add support of `https`?

My current application is deployed using the following `yaml`s.

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: name
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: somename
```

and

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: somename-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: somename
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 9000
      targetPort: 9000
  type: LoadBalancer
```

Answer (score 3):

Go to Workload > Select your App > deployment details page > Actions > Expose > Service type select Load Balancer and clicking expose will create LB for your application, using this GUI you can add Load Balancer to your GKE workload easily.

Comment: When I got to Kubernetes Engine -> Workloads, and select my cluster, I see (among other things), the 2 nodes of my application. I can't see Deployment details page. I see a +Deploy option but I suppose that is not what you mean.

Comment: @manu, I guess your application/workload name is Play, click on the application-name it will show you deployment details page

Comment: Thanks Mahboob. I was looking at the wrong place. Found it. I already have created a load balancer using the the yaml files defined. I am confused if I need another load balancer esp. as I don't have different routing rules (all traffic goes to same pods). Getting https support is the main thing I am looking for.

Comment: @ManuChadha, you can create another load balancer on different port (443)

Comment: What would be the advantage of that? Sorry, I am quite new to this stuff so have many questions!

Comment: Usually user request come through port 80 (default), you can receive it on another port as per your requirement. For more [information](https://www.ctl.io/blog/post/cloud-load-balancing/)

Answer (score 2):

You can define a [GKE ingress](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/ingress) to customize your Load Balancer. You can add annotations to customize the type of load balancer that you want, and you can [add SSL certificate](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/ingress#options_for_providing_ssl_certificates) to serve traffic in HTTPS

Comment: Thanks Guillaume. At the moment, I don't have requirement to route traffic differently based on url. Am I correct that in that case, I don't need Ingress and the standard load balancer woudl be sufficient? Or Is it a  good design practice to have an `Ingress` even if there are no spl routing requirements?

Comment: Standard is enough but if you think that you will have other services, it's better to prepare the environment now, to be sure to not have regression later when you will switch configuration (but you can test the switch in stating environment also, as you want!)